# pandas read_csv slow with European date format

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

I have a large csv file (>1M lines), with two columns with dates in European format (DD/MM/YY), that I am processing with pandas. Pandas is slow to read such files. Here are the experiments:

- `read_csv(...,parse_dates=None)` (default) treats the date columns as string (as expected) and takes < 1 seconds
- `read_csv(..., parse_dates=my_columns, dayfirst=True)` and `read_csv(..., parse_dates=my_columns, dayfirst=True, infer_datetime_format=True)` (docs suggested the latter may be faster) both give the same results: it takes ~5 minutes
- using a custom date parser `read_csv(..., parse_dates=my_columns, date_parser=lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%d/%m/%y'))` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465045/can-pandas-automatically-recognize-dates) for *weird* formatting takes 25 seconds
- not parsing the dates with `read_csv` but using `to_datetime` after

  ```
  read_csv(..., parse_dates=None)
  for column in my_columns:
    my_frame[column]=pd.to_datetime(my_frame[column], format='%d/%m/%y')
  ```

  takes 7 seconds
- as reference: opening a csv as saved by pandas (with `DataFrame.to_csv` once all the dates have been properly read) takes 2 seconds

As you can see there are a lot of discrepancies, which, I think, is fairly surprising given that it is a standard date format. So what is the correct way to read European dates?

Comment: Does it work? Yes? You have your answer :)

Comment: Sure but there has to be a better way for such a standard date format

Comment: The advantage of `to_datetime`  is that you specify the format. It's also very slow if you don't specify the format. There is an open issue about passing the date format to read_csv [here](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/2586).

Comment: Thank you @ayhan!