# Pandas read_csv converting string to datetime and saving to database Python

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, sqlalchemy

I'm currently reading from a csv file with pandas. I'd like for the column that has a string which resembles datetime to be turned into a DateTime object. I have restrictions on my database that specify that column should be of such type.

an Example row from my csv file is:

```
2015-11-28 00:10:00, 99, 21
```

I originaly faced the problem when I had the following.

```
    # import CSV file
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False)

    # TODO  Save data into db
    # ADD time, banana, apple
    for i in df.index:
        m = AggregatedMeasurement(
            time=df.loc[i, 'Time UTC'],
            banana=df.loc[i, 'BANANA'],
            apple=df.loc[i, 'APPLE']
        )
        db.session.add(m)  # add to db
    db.session.commit()  # perform them all
```

I received the following error.

```
StatementError: (builtins.TypeError) SQLite DateTime type only accepts Python datetime and date objects as input
```

I started searching here and found that one can indicate **date_parser** and started combinations. This is what I have tried so far with the help of this suggestion. [Can pandas automatically recognize dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465045/can-pandas-automatically-recognize-dates)

```
    dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

    # import CSV file
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, error_bad_lines=False, warn_bad_lines=False, parse_dates=['datetime'],
                     date_parser=dateparse)
```

and now I am getting the following error

```
ValueError: 'datetime' is not in list
```

Am I implementing this wrong? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE 1**

After the following changes

```
dateparse = lambda x: pd.datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

# import CSV file
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, error_bad_lines=False,
                      warn_bad_lines=False,
                      parse_dates=['Time UTC'],
                      date_parser=dateparse)
```

I got a `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable` on this specific part          `date_parser=dateparse)`

**UPDATE 2**
Later, I tried the next suggestion.

```
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, error_bad_lines=False,
                     warn_bad_lines=False)

    # Changing datatype
    df['Time UTC'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time UTC'])
```

And I think that worked :) I got another error but that corresponds to another database restriction relationship/ForeignKey that I haven't set up yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be a simple mistake. I think you should do this :

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, 
                 error_bad_lines=False, 
                 warn_bad_lines=False, 
                 parse_dates=['Time UTC'],
                 date_parser=dateparse)
```

Indeed, you should refer `parse_dates` to `'Time UTC'` which is the column of interest, and not `'datetime'`.

Otherwise, you may more easily let `pd.to_datetime()` handle the task, using :

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename, error_bad_lines=False,
                     warn_bad_lines=False)

# Changing datatype
df['Time UTC'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time UTC'])
```

Comment: Thank you your response. I did your suggested changes and I am facing a new error now, so I think that is progress.

New error is: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Comment: Did you try just doing `df['Time UTC'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time UTC'])` ? Can you give more information on where exactly that error happens ? (the line for ex.)

Comment: I updated the original post with the code update and the error where I got it. However, after implementing your suggestion:

 `       df = pd.read_csv(filename, error_bad_lines=False,
                         warn_bad_lines=False)

        # Changing datatype
        df['Time UTC'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time UTC'])`

It seemed to work! I got my next error(that I think is unrelated to this) :) Thank you @Arnaud. I would upvote but I don't have enough rep yet.

Comment: Perfect if that works -- I think it was indeed a cleaner way. You can still accept my answer ! Thanks