# Pandas parsing dates when reading CSV file

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file which contains a date column, the dates in this file have the format of 'dd.mm.yy', when pandas parse the dates it understands the day as a month if it was less than or equal to 12, so 05.01.05 becomes 01/05/2005.

How can I solve this issue

Regards

Comment: post few row of you data and parse code

Comment: Checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/17468012/9504749

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to solve it using `pandas.to.datetime` and setting the argument `dayfirst=True`. However, I've had to make assumptions about the format of your data since you are not sharing any code. In the case below the original format of the `date` column is `object`.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
'date': ['01.02.20', '25.12.19', '10.03.18'],
})

df = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], dayfirst=True)

df

0   2020-02-01
1   2019-12-25
2   2018-03-10
Name: date, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```