# pandas 'Date' is not in list

Tags: python, pandas

I am newbie to coding and I am trying to grab some history data from yahoo finance, and the code was work before

```
def crawl_price(stock_id):
        now = int(datetime.datetime.now().timestamp())+86400
        url = "https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/" + stock_id + "?period1=0&period2=" + str(now) + "&interval=1d&events=history&crumb=hP2rOschxO0"
        r = requests.post(url)
        f = io.StringIO(r.text)
        df = pd.read_csv(f, index_col='Date', parse_dates=['Date'])

        conn = sqlite3.connect('data/hkprice.db')
        df.to_sql('' + stock_id + '', conn, if_exists='replace')

        return df
```

but the output turns `'Date' is not in list`

and i download the csv thought open with pandas, it show perfectly fine

i am not sure what going wrong

Comment: my apologies, https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/0005.HK?period1=946857600&period2=1592352000&interval=1d&events=history

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried making a GET request instead of a POST:

```
r = requests.get(url)
```

That URL does not allow POST requests.  Here's the text returned when making the POST request:

```
r = request.post(url)
r.text
'{"finance":{"result":null,"error":{"code":"Method Not Allowed","description":"HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed"}}}'
```

Comment: it's work!! thank you so much
but how can i decide which one should i use in another scenario?

Comment: After you make the request, check the status code with r.status_code.  A successful request will return 200.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/200

Answer (score 0):

Is it 'Date' with a capital letter or 'date' without a capital letter?
Could you give an example of the intended URL? It's hard to work without an example :/

Answer (score 0):

Add seperator into the red_csv() method.

```
df = pd.read_csv(f, sep="," , index_col='Date', parse_dates=['Date'])
```

check the other parameters of read_csv like sep=";" , encoding="utf_8"  etc.

Comment: i try ',' and';' , also the encoding to utf_8, but it seems not work as expected, still ValueError: 'Date' is not in list

Comment: Check this --->  [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465045/can-pandas-automatically-recognize-dates)