# dataframe transformation of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to manipulate the dataframe element into the data type of the element.
the example below dataframe.

```
A      B         C           D
1      2       12-03-2010   1
45     acxz    3-02-2010    3
43     2.9     14-08-2010   4
45.3   3.5     23-09-2019   2.46
nan    34.23   09-09-2020   09-02-2015
45     nan     sam          10-09-2016
24     45.23   02-03-2021   wax
xyz    32      raz          na
```

Transform this dataframe into below dataframe.

```
A        B         C         D
int     int     datetime    int
int     string  datetime    int
int     float   datetime    int
float   float   datetime    float
string  float   datetime    datetime
int     string  string      datetime
int     float   datetime    string
string  int     string      string
```

can anyone suggest me any way to achieve the below dataframe from the above data using pandas.

Comment: @jezrael but head only extract at max 5 data without argument and below one is new dataframe from the above dataframe.

Comment: so, since `head` is the issue in the example code from jezrael, all you need to do is....

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) by types, convert to strings and last use `replace`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "a": [1, 0.01, 'aaa', pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01')],
    "b": ['yy', pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01'), 1, 0]
   
})

d = {"<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>":'datetime',
     "<class 'int'>":'int',
     "<class 'float'>":'float',
     "<class 'str'>":'string'}
df = df.applymap(type).astype(str).replace(d)
print (df)
          a         b
0       int    string
1     float  datetime
2    string       int
3  datetime       int
```

Comment: how you are generating d variable dictonary.

Comment: @Rishav - Manually, it is only for replace

Comment: great @Jezrael.

Comment: @jezreal yes, but need to check for Nan values.

Comment: @jezreal getting issue with DateTime, the above script treats it as a string, not as DateTime.

Comment: @Rishav - it means in input data are datetimes like strings.

Comment: @jezreal to input the data in dataframe I am using read_csv(path,engine='python') it will auto-detect datatime columns of input data. Is there any way to handle the auto conversion?

Comment: @Rishav - No, there is no such option, you need [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465045/can-pandas-automatically-recognize-dates) for set values manually