# Dropping rows from pandas dataframe with some function on the series

Tags: python, pandas, datetime-format, python-datetime

I am trying to drop outdated values from a dataframe that holds a difficult to compare date format.
My code:

```
frame=pd.read_csv("somefile.csv")
frame=frame[datetime.strptime(frame["CreationTime"],"%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")>(datetime.now()-timedelta(days=daypar))]
```

However I get the error that the 1st arg of strptime should be str and not Series, Which makes sense.
So how would one go about solving this issue?

Comment: You can use `pd.to_datetime(frame['CreationTime'], format="%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")` to convert to datetime and drop in a second step.

Comment: Also see this answer for parsing dates directly on loading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465045/can-pandas-automatically-recognize-dates

Comment: I tried ```pd.to_datetime(frame['CreationTime'], format="%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")``` which errored with " TypeError: Unrecognized value type: <class 'str'>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas `read_csv` is clever enough to decode timestamps at load time:

```
frame=pd.read_csv("somefile.csv", parse_dates=['CreationTime'])
frame=frame[df['CreationTime']>(datetime.now()-timedelta(days=daypar))]
```