# Recreating a plot and not coming out the same way

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to recreate a graph from a professor's example. This is what he did:

```
axes = sns.regplot(x=miami.Date, y=miami.Temperature)
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.title('Regression analysis of Miami Temps')
```

but when I do it the graph looks weird, it comes out like this:

[Graph from matplotlib and seaborn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/daXLy.png)

Why are the data points like this and how do I make it so that it looks normal (so they aren't only on the far left and right)?

This is the desired
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8w5CB.png)

Comment: You might want to add an image of your expected plot so people can see the discrepancy.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] including input (data), complete code, and expected output.

Comment: desired plot added

Comment: Your 'Date' column isn't in a nice date format. Did you read your data with `read_csv()`? See e.g. [Can pandas automatically recognize dates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17465045/can-pandas-automatically-recognize-dates)