# import dataframe with milliseconds in timestamp

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I got a file, which contains a timestamp like '15:05:26:811'.

If I try to import it into pandas with

```
data = pd.read_csv(file, sep='\t', names=['Time', 'x-data', index_col = False, dtype = float)
```

I get the error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '15:05:26:811'
```

What do I have to do? Just remove "dtype = float"? This might work, but will this lead to problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can parse the string column to a datetime object after reading the csv:

```
data['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S:%f')
```

If you want to parse the string while reading the csv, add a dedicated parser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17468012/5316326

Comment: Thx for your reply. However, this gives me this error: time data '15:11:25:401' does not match format '%H:%M:%S.%f' (match)

Comment: sorry, should be '%H:%M:%S:%f'. I'll udate the answer