# Datetime mixes day and month when converting strings to datetime format

Tags: python, pandas, csv, datetime

I'm working with a dataset that has a date column in the format `dd-mm-yyyy`, however this column is an object and I need it to be datetime format in order to extract the month of the date. However, when using the function `pd.to_datetime`, the dates that represent the beginning of a month, like `11-02-2022`, are being converted to `2022-11-02`, when it really should be `2022-02-11`. So when I try to extract the month, the result is `11` instead of `02`. This doesn't happen with dates like: `31-03-2022` as it is converted to `2022-03-31`, and the month is `03`.

This is my code:

```
data_flights['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_flights['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
data_flights['month'] = data_flights['date'].dt.month
```

And this is the output in my dataset:
[table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kGWA.png)

If I use `dayfirst = True`, the same still happens.
I'm using python 3.9, and jupyter.

My data comes from 2 csv files. One contains information about economy class tickets and the other one about business class tickets. Both datasets have this format:

```
date,airline,ch_code,num_code,dep_time,from,time_taken,stop,arr_time,to,price
11-02-2022,Air India,AI,868,18:00,Delhi,02h 00m,non-stop ,20:00,Mumbai,"25,612"
11-02-2022,Air India,AI,624,19:00,Delhi,02h 15m,non-stop ,21:15,Mumbai,"25,612"
11-02-2022,Air India,AI,531,20:00,Delhi,24h 45m,"1-stop",20:45,Mumbai,"42,220"
11-02-2022,Air India,AI,839,21:25,Delhi,26h 30m,"1-stop",23:55,Mumbai,"44,450"
```

The way I loaded both datasets is:

```
data_economy = pd.read_csv('economy.csv')
data_business = pd.read_csv('business.csv')
```

And then I merged both like this:

```
economy_df = data_economy.assign(ticket_class = 0)
business_df = data_business.assign(ticket_class = 1)
data_flights = pd.concat([economy_df,business_df])
```

Comment: What database are you working with? If you mean a traditional relational database system such as PostgreSQL, MySQL, etc. - their date typed fields don't have _any_ format.  Thus any format you're seeing has been applied upon retrieval or output.  You'd need to show that code here.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint Thank you so much for your question. I'm working with a csv file and the column 'data' has a dtype object, which is why I'm trying to covert it to datetime.

Comment: Thanks for the detail.  Please edit your question to include a small example of the data from the csv file, and also the code you use to read the csv file, along with any code you may have for parsing dates.  Also, you may want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17468012/634824).

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I already edited the question, thank you so much for your feedback. I'll read what you suggested.

Comment: closing this as not reproducible, see Zach Young's answer below. `pd.to_datetime(data_flights['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')` is the correct way to parse a Series of dates as strings with format like 11-02-2022 (dd-mm-yyyy).

Answer (score 1):

I cannot see from the info you provided how you got a month of 11, and only for the economy dataset.  Maybe I missed some detail in the question.

I tried running your code on the sample CSV you provided and it looks like Pandas correctly parses the date, based on the format "day-month-year".

```py
import pandas as pd

dtfmt_dmy = r"%d-%m-%Y"

df_economy = pd.read_csv("input1.csv")

df_economy["date"] = pd.to_datetime(df_economy["date"], format=dtfmt_dmy)
df_economy.insert(1, "month", df_economy["date"].dt.month)

print(df_economy)
```

And I get a month of 2:

```
       date  month    airline ch_code  num_code dep_time   from time_taken       stop arr_time      to   price
0 2022-02-11      2  Air India      AI       868    18:00  Delhi    02h 00m  non-stop     20:00  Mumbai  25,612
1 2022-02-11      2  Air India      AI       624    19:00  Delhi    02h 15m  non-stop     21:15  Mumbai  25,612
2 2022-02-11      2  Air India      AI       531    20:00  Delhi    24h 45m     1-stop    20:45  Mumbai  42,220
3 2022-02-11      2  Air India      AI       839    21:25  Delhi    26h 30m     1-stop    23:55  Mumbai  44,450
```

I can then save that modified df, again using the same date-format string:

```py
df_economy.to_csv("output.csv", date_format=dtfmt_dmy)
```

and my output.csv looks like:

```
| Idx | date       | month | airline   | ch_code | num_code | dep_time | from  | time_taken | stop      | arr_time | to     | price  |
|-----|------------|-------|-----------|---------|----------|----------|-------|------------|-----------|----------|--------|--------|
| 0   | 11-02-2022 | 2     | Air India | AI      | 868      | 18:00    | Delhi | 02h 00m    | non-stop  | 20:00    | Mumbai | 25,612 |
| 1   | 11-02-2022 | 2     | Air India | AI      | 624      | 19:00    | Delhi | 02h 15m    | non-stop  | 21:15    | Mumbai | 25,612 |
| 2   | 11-02-2022 | 2     | Air India | AI      | 531      | 20:00    | Delhi | 24h 45m    | 1-stop    | 20:45    | Mumbai | 42,220 |
| 3   | 11-02-2022 | 2     | Air India | AI      | 839      | 21:25    | Delhi | 26h 30m    | 1-stop    | 23:55    | Mumbai | 44,450 |
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you define a date parser, and then use it on the specific column named `date` when you are parsing:

```
from datetime import datetime
dateparse = lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%d')

data_economy = pd.read_csv('economy.csv', parse_dates=['date'], date_parser=dateparse)
data_business = pd.read_csv('business.csv', parse_dates=['date'], date_parser=dateparse)
```

Or if you have Pandas 2.0.0 or newer, use `date_format` instead of `date_parser`:

```
data_economy = pd.read_csv('economy.csv', parse_dates=['date'], date_format='%Y-%m-%d')
data_business = pd.read_csv('business.csv', parse_dates=['date'], date_format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

Then you can delete this line:

```
data_flights['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data_flights['date'], format='%d-%m-%Y')
```

... because the data will already be parsed as date in the correct format.

Refer to Panda's [`read_csv` docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) for further details and examples.